# Change text of item in dropdown

Tags: javascript, c#, combobox, devexpress-mvc

In a devexpress combobox control I'm trying to change the display `text` of an `item`. I know how to get the item, I'm using `FindItemByValue` but when I get the `item` and change its `text` property, the text doesn't actually change.

I tried to do an `alert` of the text after changing it, and the alert shows the changed text, but the item in the combobox dropdown is still the original value.

```
 var billingContactObject = 
    clientContactListComboBox.FindItemByValue(hiddenContactIdForBilling);
 if (billingContactObject != null) {
    var text = billingContactObject.text + "*"
    billingContactObject.text = text;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use function `SetText(text)`. In your case:

```
var billingContactObject = clientContactListComboBox.FindItemByValue(hiddenContactIdForBilling);
clientContactListComboBox.SetText(billingContactObject.text + "*");
```

ComboBox item has a lot of useful functions like `SetValue(value)`, `SetSelectedIndex(index)`, `AddItem` and others. Yo can check its on devexpress website for example: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#aspnet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientListEdit_SetSelectedIndextopic